# Strange behaviour with controller and view inside area MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have one area called `user`.

The area configuration looks like this

```
context.MapRouteLowercase(name: "User_Member", url: "User/Member", defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Member", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

When I browse to this page without passing in a id, it returns the view my url looks like this   `/user/member`

When I type the following into the browser `/user/member/1`

I've put a break point on

`var userId`

and it gets hit and I check the id parameter and its 1 which is correct.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Member(Int64 id = 0)
    {
        var userId = id != 0 ? id : ReturnUserId();

        var model = _userProfileBusinessLayer.GetProfile(userId);

        return View(model);
    }
```

Yet when I press F5 I get the following page

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The view 'member' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/user/member.aspx
~/Views/user/member.ascx
~/Views/Shared/member.aspx
~/Views/Shared/member.ascx
~/Views/user/member.cshtml
~/Views/user/member.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/member.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/member.vbhtml
```

I'm unsure why I'm seeing that because all I have done is added `/1` to the url?

I should be seeing the profile of the user which matches then id of 1, yet I remove `/1` and it returns the view ?!?!?!?! slightly baffled

Comment: What is Member is it a view or partial view? try shift it to shared folder and it should work.

Comment: @GirishSakhare its a view, and I was missing {id} off the end of the area configuration it's now working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In your project, the area `user` should have a class that inherits from `AreaRegistration` e.g.

```
public class UserAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "user";
        }
    }
}
```

In that class you can define routes sepcific for that area:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "UserManagement",
        "user/Admin",
        new { controller = "UserAdmin", action = "Index" });
}
```

The file Global.asax.cs should have an Application_Start() method which calls:

`AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();`

That will pick up the area routes you have configured. This is usually how area routes are configured. Do you have a similar setup for your project?